# why webgrid always pass default

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i make editable webgrid, when i pass value for webgrid, i allways give default value for checkbox. when value in database is "TRUE", after edited checkbox to false, value will pass "TRUE" seams like value in database. can some one help me

this my view

```
<div>
    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(Model.DataDiriList, rowsPerPage: 15, canPage: true, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
        @grid.GetHtml(
                           tableStyle: "row",
                  alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                  columns: grid.Columns(
                  grid.Column("ID", format: @<text>  <span  class="display-mode">@item.ID </span> <label id="UserID" class="edit-mode">@item.ID</label> </text>, style: "col1Width" ),
                  grid.Column("Nama", "Nama", format: @<text>  <span  class="display-mode"> <label id="lblNama"  >@item.Nama</label> </span> <input type="text" id="Nama" value="@item.Nama" class="edit-mode" /></text>, style: "col2Width"),
                  grid.Column("Umur", "Umur", format: @<text>  <span  class="display-mode"> <label id="lblUmur"  >@item.Umur</label> </span> <input type="text" id="Umur" value="@item.Umur" class="edit-mode" /></text>, style: "col2Width"),
                  grid.Column(header: "Active", format:@<text> <span  class="display-mode"> @Html.Raw("<input type=\"checkbox\" " + ((item.Active == true) ? "checked='cheked'" : "") + "disabled = 'disabled'/>") </span> <input id="chkActive" type="checkbox" @(item.Active ? " checked=checked" : null) name="CloseSelling" value="@item.Active" class="edit-mode" /></text>, style: "col2Width"),
                  grid.Column("Action", format: @<text>
                                <button class="edit-user display-mode" >Edit</button>
                                <button class="save-user edit-mode"  >Save</button>
                                <button class="cancel-user edit-mode" >Cancel</button>
                            </text>,  style: "col3Width" , canSort: false)
                 ));
    }
</div>

@section scripts
    {
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.edit-mode').hide();
            $('.edit-user, .cancel-user').on('click', function () {
                var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
                tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();
            });



            $(".save-user").on("click", function () {
                var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
                var t = tr.find("#Nama").val();
                var Umur = tr.find('#Umur').val();
                var ID = tr.find('#UserID').html();
                var chkActive = tr.find('#chkActive').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateUser", "Home")',
                type: "Post",
                data: { CustomerNameId: t, UserID: ID, Umur: Umur,Active: chkActive},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#mygrid").html('');
                    $("#mygrid").html(result);
                }
                });

                tr.find("#lblNama").text(t);
                tr.find("#lblUmur").text(Umur);
                tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();
        });

    });
</script>
    }
```

MY Controller

```
public JsonResult UpdateUser(string CustomerNameId, string UserID, string Umur, bool Active)
        {
            var ID = Convert.ToInt32(UserID);
            var IntUmur = Convert.ToInt32(Umur);
            var dd = db.DataDiris.AsQueryable().Where(r => r.ID == ID).Single();
            dd.ID = ID;
            dd.Nama = CustomerNameId;
            dd.Umur = IntUmur;

            db.Entry(dd).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            string message = "Success";
            return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: You do not pass `Active` value to data base you have to do it like this in your controller `dd.Active = Active;`. I think that is your problem.

Comment: You have to do this `tr.find('#chkActive').is(':checked')` instead of  `tr.find('#chkActive').val();`. if you do this `tr.find('#chkActive').is(':checked')` you find checkbox is true or false.